# SQLite Query to String

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I want to put an table content to a string if a listview item is selected.

My actual query

```
    public Cursor webUrlQuery() {
    String webUrlTmp = "select weburl FROM stations WHERE name=" + "'" + name + "'";
    return database.rawQuery(webUrlTmp, null);
}
```

works. But if I log it to logcat via

```
Log.d(TAG, "webUrl = " + webUrlQuery());
```

or

```
Log.d(TAG, "webUrl = " + webUrlQuery().toString());
```

I got something like this:

> 12-30 23:25:15.828: D/StationsActivity(10576): streamUrl = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4132fce0

How can I get an string which I can use? 
It seems that the method, cursor.toString() dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many results you're expecting. If you only expect one result, you could use something like this:

```
Cursor result = webUrlQuery();
result.moveToFirst();
String url = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("weburl"));
Log.d(TAG, "webUrl = " + url);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Thats exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

`Cursor.toString()` is working perfectly fine - it's returning a string representation of the `Cursor` object. You presumably want [`Cursor.getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) (and I believe you'll first need to use [`Cursor.moveToFirst()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) to point to the first returned row).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to logcat the `Cursor` object? If you want to print the query, you need to use `webUrlTmp`.

BTW, you should really consider binding your query parameters.

Comment: I have an listview, with certain items (out of my qslite db). If on item is selected, I want to set a string to one db item. In this example above a url. Logcat is only for testing. :)
But if I logcat the webUrlTmp is get only null. Why? If I use sqlite on my device (in adb) I got the right url's.